# How do I parse part of a JSON object that has mixed string and numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sql-server, database

I have a JSON file that was processor generated with lines like this

```
jsonData:   "{data: [350.23,250.32,150.34,340.50,236.70,370.45,380.55]}"
```

I can target the 'jsonData' object but that returns everything within the double quotes as a string.
I tried ...dataset[0].jsonData[8] which returns the '3' from the first value. I guess I could throw the mixed strings into a JS function and use regex to remove the extra stuff, but thats probably the hackyest way to do this.

Whats the easiest way to target the values only?

Comment: That string is not valid JSON. Works fine with a proper JSON string: `JSON.parse('{"data": [350.23,250.32,150.34,340.50,236.70,370.45,380.55]}')`

Comment: You're not being very clear about what you're trying to accomplish by "targeting" and "extra stuff".  But `JSON.parse()` might get you somewhere.

Comment: Im using axios that includes the JSON.parse(), when I try retrieving the data the string <<{data: [350.23,250.32,150.34,340.50,236.70,370.45,380.55]}>> is what i get. I know the processor is messing up the JSON but this is what I have to work with. Can I do something to 'target' the double values only?

Comment: What has SQL Server got to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interact with it like the list I would consider something like

```
var list = jsonData.split("[")[1].split("]")[0].split(",")

Console.log(list);
```

The console reads:

```
[
  '350.23', '250.32',
  '150.34', '340.50',
  '236.70', '370.45',
  '380.55'
]
```

From here you can use list[3] to get 340.50

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to spend the time fixing your JSON just do this:

```
let values = "{data: [350.23,250.32,150.34,340.50,236.70,370.45,380.55]}".split(',').map(_ => _.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''))

console.log(values)
```